# How to combine fields and arrays in FileMaker?

Tags: arrays, xml, xslt, filemaker

I have developed an API, which returns for example this xml:

```
<ApiResult xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ErrorCode>0</ErrorCode>
    <IsSuccess>true</IsSuccess>
    <Message>ok</Message>
    <Data xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
        <d2p1:string>Standard</d2p1:string>
        <d2p1:string>50%</d2p1:string>
        <d2p1:string>Großkunden</d2p1:string>
        <d2p1:string>100%</d2p1:string>
        <d2p1:string>Basis 7,-</d2p1:string>
        <d2p1:string>Großladebonus</d2p1:string>
        <d2p1:string>Neu</d2p1:string>
        <d2p1:string>test</d2p1:string>
        <d2p1:string>Test</d2p1:string>
    </Data>
</ApiResult>
```

My task is to create a XML Transformation for the import. That is my XSLT so far:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <FMPXMLRESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult">
      <METADATA>
        <FIELD NAME="ErrorCode" TYPE="NUMBER"/>
        <FIELD NAME="IsSuccess" TYPE="TEXT"/>
        <FIELD NAME="Message" TYPE="TEXT"/>
      </METADATA>
      <RESULTSET>
        <ROW>
          <COL>
            <DATA>
              <xsl:value-of select="ApiResult/ErrorCode"/>
            </DATA>
          </COL>
          <COL>
            <DATA>
              <xsl:value-of select="ApiResult/IsSuccess"/>
            </DATA>
          </COL>
          <COL>
            <DATA>
              <xsl:value-of select="ApiResult/Message"/>
            </DATA>
          </COL>
        </ROW>
      </RESULTSET>
    </FMPXMLRESULT>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am stuck at including my `Data`-Array of type `string`. How can I include it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am stuck at including my Data-Array of type string. How can I
>   include it?

I am not sure how exactly you want to import them. You don't have fields for them in the `METADATA` section, and they don't have any labels to give me a clue what they represent.

Assuming the entire array is a single record, and that the structure of the array is constant, you could do something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"
exclude-result-prefixes="d2p1">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/ApiResult">
    <FMPXMLRESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult">
        <METADATA>
            <FIELD NAME="ErrorCode" TYPE="NUMBER"/>
            <FIELD NAME="IsSuccess" TYPE="TEXT"/>
            <FIELD NAME="Message" TYPE="TEXT"/>
            <FIELD NAME="Field1" TYPE="TEXT"/>
            <FIELD NAME="Field2" TYPE="TEXT"/>
            <FIELD NAME="Field3" TYPE="TEXT"/>
            <!-- ADD MORE FIELDS AS NEEDED  -->
        </METADATA>
        <RESULTSET>
            <ROW>
                <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="ErrorCode"/></DATA></COL>
                <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="IsSuccess"/></DATA></COL>
                <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="Message"/></DATA></COL>
                <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="Data/d2p1:string[1]"/></DATA></COL>
                <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="Data/d2p1:string[2]"/></DATA></COL>
                <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="Data/d2p1:string[3]"/></DATA></COL>
                <!-- ADD MORE DATA STRINGS AS NEEDED  -->
            </ROW>
        </RESULTSET>
    </FMPXMLRESULT>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The above will enable you to import the first three Data strings. You will see the field names `Field1`, `Field2` and `Field3` in the left pane of the Import Records dialog (of course, you can change these names in the stylesheet to match your target field names).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there a more dynamic way? It could be only 3 strings, but it could also be 999 strings.

Comment: Or other formulated: Is it possible two have multiple `RESULTSET`s? One for the status of the operation and one for the actualy result?

Comment: There is a dynamic way in XSLT, but not in FileMaker. You cannot add 999 fields to your solution during the import. The only reasonable solution would be to import each string as a separate record. I am not sure what you would do with them in this format, though. Without labels they seem meaningless.

Comment: It's not possible to have multiple RESULTSETs. I am not sure you need to import the status of the operation (if it failed, I doubt the import will take place) but if you do, you could use global fields for this.

Comment: It is realy hard to find an documented example of `global field`. Since I am coming from the C#/Web Stack, I am realy inexperienced with filemaker. Do you have by chance a reference link? Thanks again.

Comment: http://www.filemaker.com/help/15/fmp/en/#page/FMP_Help%2Fglobal-fields.html%23 -- P.S. Consider joining one of the forums dedicated to the FileMaker platforms.